# Input Iterator - Star and Postfix-Operator

Tags: c++, iterator

Is it valid to do this on an input iterator `*it++` ?

I understand the code as follow, that it dereference the iterator and gives  me the value and then step one ahead.

In the c++ reference the * operator is lower than the postfix operator: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

But I read this style is bad practice. Why?

Comment: Because postfix `++` should record the previous state then self plus, there is some additional work to be done comparing with prefix `++`. That's just why using `++i` in `foo` loop is recommended.

Comment: I don't think it's considered bad style, it's a common idiom. Like `*dest++ = *src++` in a loop that copies from one array to another.

Comment: @Barmar For pointers yes, but there has long been a preference for preincrement on iterators because postincrement is significantly more expensive for at least some iterators.

Comment: @AlanStokes Won't that skip the first element and try to dereference past the end?

Comment: @Barmar You do need to rewrite appropriately. `*dest = *src; ++dest; ++src;` for example.

Comment: @DanielLangr But I think this will have a different side-effect because the precedence of prefix++ is the same than the * operator.but right to left evaluation. And your two code samples should have the same side-effect but the bracets clarify the precedence.

Comment: @thomas You're right, didn't realize this before. Will delete my comment. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it valid to do this on an input iterator `*it++`?

Yes, that is valid.  The iterator will be incremented, its previous value will be returned, and you will dereference that returned iterator.

> But I read this style is bad practice. Why?

Consider these two implementations I've just pulled out of some graph code I wrote a while back:

```
// Pre-increment
BidirectionalIterator& operator++()
{
    edge = (edge->*elem).next;
    return *this;
}

// Post-increment
BidirectionalIterator operator++(int)
{
    TargetIterator oldval(list, edge);
    edge = (edge->*elem).next;
    return oldval;
}
```

Notice that for post-increment, I need to first construct a new iterator to store the previous value which will be returned.

If it's simple and clear to write your program to make use of pre-increment, there may be better performance, less work for the compiler to do, or both.

Just don't go crazy on this (for example, rewriting all your loops)!  That would likely be micro-optimization.  However, the reason people say it's good practice is that if you get into a habit of using pre-increment as default then you get (potentially) better performance by default.